# ¿Como subir una aplicacion de Shiny Dashboard (en R) a la red interna para que otros empelados la vean?

Tags: r, windows, shiny

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para subir mi shiny dashboard a la red interna de la empresa para que la puedan ver los demás empleados?
Existe alguna forma de que yo pueda exportar las paginas para que luego en la red interna poner algun link para abrir el archivo con la informacion del shiny?
O conocen alguna forma economica y practica para poder consultar la informacion del shiny dashboard? Esto por que estoy haciendo la practica profesional en esta empresa.

Edit 1.
Además que personas externas a la empresa no puedan acceder.

Comment: La pregunta fundamental es si vas a compartir un app de shinny, con usuarios que ya tienen R/RStudio o necesitas un hosting completo?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Saludos Patricio, seria para cualquier persona de la empresa por lo que supongo que sea un hosting ya que solo yo manejo el R/R-studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empecemos por: **¿Que componentes tiene una aplicación `shiny`?** básicamente:

- (a) El Interprete de R
- (b) el código completo R de tus scripts
- (c) Cualquier librería que necesite tu aplicación
- (d) Un web server que exponga la aplicación bajo un protocolo `http`
- (e) Cualquier fuente de datos que requiera tu aplicación.

Rstudio implementa "automagicamente" todo esto de forma transparente, de manera que si haces un `"run app"` de tu script, a los segundos tendrás un mini servidor web funcionando localmente, y se abrirá automáticamente un navegador apuntando a la página de tu app.

Distribuir o compartir todo lo comentado anteriormente, no es trivial pero si es posible. Básicamente hay algunas posibles formas de hacerlo:

- Usar tu equipo de webserver, simplemente ejecutas tu script mediante `runApp(host="0.0.0.0", port=<port>)`, y deberás configurar un puerto válido que permita al resto de los usuarios de la red interna acceder a tu equipo, y tomar nota de la dirección `ip` que tengas asignada, para compartirla con tus colegas. Suponiendo que tu `ip` sea `192.168.1.70` y tu port `8080` el acceso de ellos sería por medio del navegador indicando la dirección: `192.168.1.70:8080`. Esto claro, solo funciona en la medida que tengas tu app corriendo y que efectivamente tu equipo pueda hacer de webserver.
- [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/): Es un servicio gratuito para publicar aplicaciones en la nube. Simplemente te tienes que registrar, el proceso de "subir" la aplicación es trivial en este caso, si mal no recuerdo, puedes crear un proyecto "shiny" de Rstudio y ya dispones de un un botón para publicar la app en la nube que hace todo el trabajo. Deberás evaluar las limitaciones de volumen de consultas o espacio y el tema permisos, ten en cuenta que tu app estaría eventualmente disponible para todo el mundo.
- Servidores "as-hoc": Por último, cabría la posibilidad de implementar tu propio servidor shiny. Esto no es trivial ya que requiere instalar y configurar un servidor específico para albergar este tipo de aplicación. Hay una alternativa "open source" llamada [`Shiny Server`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/blob/master/README.md), creada por el equipo de Rstudio, y por supuesto la versión comercial  [`RStudio Connect`](https://rstudio.com/products/connect/)

Comment: me gusta la primera opcion, tengo tres preguntas, 1. puedo seguir usando la computadora para otras tareas si esta funcionando como servidor? 2. A que se refiere con que el equipo pueda hacer de webserver? Para ser webserver se necesita que la maquina tenga algun hardware o software en especifico? 3. para la ip y el port tengo que solicitarlo a soporte? Gracias.

Comment: 1. Si puedes seguir usándola, lógicamente, más usuarios conectados, más recursos que te irán quitando. 2. Cualquier equipo puede funcionar como webserver, mínimamente debería poder abrir un puerto para la comunicación via http, que eso entra dentro de la directivas del área de IT de tu empresa 3. Depende que tan estrictos sean, sin duda, harías bien en consultar con ellos acerca de lo que piensas hacer.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!